# what is the difference between {!s} and {:s} in python?

Tags: python

for example if i write

```
outfile.write(('{!s}'.format(word))
```

or

```
outfile.write(('{:s}'.format(word))
```

Tried to search this everywhere but can't find anything...

Comment: ! signals a [value-conversion flag...](https://pyformat.info/#conversion_flags)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: want to put that in an answer? I could not find it in the official documentation under `str.format`, nor in [likely priors on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+string+format+value+conversion+flag) under that name.